Developing Alarm clock app - How to bring app to the front (Redmi issue)
I am developing an Alarm clock, It is working on most Android except for Redmi
The problem is that if the app is in the bg, then it doesn't trigger the alarm intent
code:
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    println("message>> AlarmReceiver onReceive")

    val alarm = needToPlayAlarm(context)
    if (alarm != null) {
        // Acquire a wake lock to ensure the CPU keeps running
        val powerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        val wakeLock =
                powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::AlarmWakeLock")

        // Acquire the wake lock, and set a timeout in case something goes wrong
        wakeLock.acquire(60 * 1000L /* 1 minutes */)

        // Launch the MainActivity with an extra flag to indicate alarm mode
        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        alarmIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK // or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        alarmIntent.putExtra("ALARM_ID", alarm.id) // Add the extra flag here

        context.startActivity(alarmIntent)

        // Release the wake lock after starting the activity to prevent unnecessary battery
        // drain
        wakeLock.release()
    }
    rescheduleAlarm(context, Alarm.ALARM_RESCHEDULE_INTERVAL_SECONDS)
}

I tried:
Xiaomi Go to the Battery => Power => App battery Saver => select your app and choose No restrictions (for Background settings), then Allow option for Background location.
To AutoStart your app after Boot: Go to the Security app => Permissions => Auto start and check your app
alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
alarmIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- For apps with targetSDK 31 (Android 12) and newer -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

I searched every possible resource, advised with senior Android developers
nothing seems to work
By now, I'm pretty sure it is a dead end, but maybe someone could shed some light on this topic?
10x
